# Problems with Color class (System.Drawing) in UWP on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I struggle to implement some basic operations with Color class on my Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT. After I instantiate a Color object by rgb data 
basic methods like GetBrightness() or GetSaturation() lead to a SEHException.

```
Thrown exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
```

Typing the operation in the "immediate window" in Visual Studio during debugging yields the desired result though. I don't even know where to start to locate the actual issue.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2b with Windows 10 IoT Core 17763 (also project build setting), and trying to run an C# UWP-Project on it.

I tried several target versions and also updated my machine. Didn't help so far.

```
// using System.Drawing;
Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(x, y, z);                
float brt = color1.GetBrightness(); // <= Not passing this line
float sat = color1.GetSaturation();
```

Like mentioned, the results in immediate window seem plausible and works at least. Why this isn't also running in code. Where is the code actually processed, that is typed in the immediate window?

Comment: You may need Windows.UI.Color in UWP

Comment: Hi, that doesn't provide GetHue() etc. at least i cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**System.Drawing** is not possible in Windows Universal app, it is the .NET namespace for working with GDI+.
You can make use of [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX) which provides wrappers for Direct2D, DirectWrite, and the Windows Imaging Component (WIC). The GetHue method is included in [ColorBGRA.cs](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Mathematics/ColorBGRA.cs).

Comment: thank you for your time. Till now i was not aware that i was supposed to double check if the using which VS suggested me is actually available in the overall UWP namespace. 
Basic color operations could also be useful in UWP though. 
I'll implement the class you have pointed at